# Evaluate classification models when dependent(target) varaible is not there in test dataset

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-science

How to evaluate classification models to select best if the dependent (target)variable is not there on test dataset?

Comment: By dependent variable you mean labels for your data?

Comment: Can you give some examples of your dataset?